# How to track nevigation of iframe using js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, url, iframe

I am using iframe to display another cross platform site
I wanted to know the url the user visited inside a iframe tag I know it need same origin policy, but it doesn't allow it
When the user changes the navigation and refreshes the parent page, the iframe returns to the original stage, but I want to change it to the user's last visited page in the iframe. Is it possible?
I have tried this:

```
iframe.contentWindow.console[logType] = function() {
    logUtil.log.apply(logUtil, arguments);
    original.apply(iframe.contentWindow.console, arguments);
};
```

Comment: You do not get access to the URL of an iframe loaded from a different origin. What you want would only be possible, if that other site was willing to actively work together with you, using `postMessage` to exchange information with the page that embedded it.